# kernel development, physical addresses and virtual addresses

Tags: kernel, x86-64, bootloader, osdev

I'm writing an operating system (kernel) as a hobby and I have a problem with the "boot boot" bootloader:
When my kernel's main() is loaded I retrieve screen pointers to display text on the screen.

When I enable paging in my kernel the physical addresses are no longer visible, of course, because paging has been enabled.
I created a macro that allows me to transform addresses from physical to virtual and vice versa.

The question is how can I make the physical address pointing to the screen (fb on bootboot) when the paging is enabled ?

Comment: I haven't used bootboot, but looking at the docs it appears you are making a 64-bit kernel. It appears that bootboot actually maps the framebuffer into virtual address space at 0xFFFFFFFF_FC000000 as part of its startup processing before handing over to your kernel. Without seeing your code and how you do things this is rather difficult to answer in an adequate way.

Comment: Or are you having issues because the framebuffer you want to use is the textmode framebuffer?

Comment: What architecture is this for Intel/AMD64 x86-64? Something else?

Comment: Intel/AMD64 x86-64

Comment: my macros: KERNEL_BASE 0xffff800000000000

Comment: P2V(p) ((uint64_t)(p) + KERNEL_BASE)

Comment: V2P(v) ((uint64_t)(v) - KERNEL_BASE)

Comment: uint64_t setup_kernvm(void)
{
    uint64_t page_map = (uint64_t)kalloc();

    if (page_map != 0) {
        memset((void*)page_map, 0, PAGE_SIZE);        
        if (!map_pages(page_map, KERNEL_BASE, P2V(0x40000000), V2P(KERNEL_BASE), PTE_P|PTE_W)) {
            free_vm(page_map);
            page_map = 0;
        }
    }
    return page_map;
}

Comment: Please edit your question with your code. Don't use comments